# Mudar status de aluno de ativo para inativo

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um banco onde salvo o status = 1 para ativo, e 2 para inativo. Tem algum modo de eu implantar na página a escrita ou um botão (ou link na palavra) "ativo" e quando clicar, mudar para "inativo" e troca no server de 1 para 0, sem refresh na página.

Sei fazer as consultas com php até exibir o status, mas não sei criar o link com o palavra e chamar o javascript e atualizar novamente. 
Qual é o melhor método ? Algum código de exemplo ?

Comment: Use um `mysqli_query` com `UPDATE table SET status=status WHERE id in ('id_do_aluno')`

Comment: Ai que está amigo, mas sem refresh ? fazer um uptade eu se, toda a parte do php é tranquilo, o problema é mudar o nome de ativo para inativo com o javascript ou alguma outra forma.

Comment: e se fosse um `.php` externo?

Comment: Sim, pensei que poderia sem um javascript que chama um php externo com POST e depois consulta novo status e volta pra página e atualiza apenas a palavra ativo.

Comment: O problema é que não sei como fazer isto com javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar AJAX, tudo deverá ser feito por outra página e a em que o usuário está só vai mandar os comandos(fazer as requisições)

**Exemplo de Código**

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
function makeRequest(acao) { //chame a função dizendo qual será a ação 
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'action.php?action='+acao); //Diga o método e a URL 
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){ //Quando o retorno estiver pronto
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {//Processo concluído
            alertContents(); //Função que dirá que a função foi completada
        }
    }
}
```

**Action.php**

A action.php deverá estar pronta para executar as ações quando for acessada vamos supor que a função makeRequest(), foi chamada da seguinte forma : makeRequest('inativo'), o php terá que está com a um código parecido com esse:

```
switch ($_GET['action']){
   case 'inativo':
      //o que o php deverá fazer
   ;
}
```

**Botão**

1° Importe a biblioteca JQuery `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>`coloque antes do fechamento da tag `body`.

2° Função alertContents() Logo após importar a biblioteca JQuery use o seguinte código :

```
function alertContents(){
   if($('#button').html() == '<button id="ativo">Deixar Ativo</button>'){
      $('#button').html('<button id="inativo">Deixar Inativo</button>')
        }
   else{
      $('#button').html('<button id="ativo">Deixar Ativo</button>');
    }
    }
```

Dentro de uma tag script

3. Botão:

No php coloque o código do botão dentro div com o id 'button' antes da importação da biblioteca JQuery sendo:

**Para inativo** `<button id="inativo">Deixar Inativo</button>`

**Para Ativo** `<button id="ativo">Deixar Ativo</button>`

4. Clique no botão

Na tag script em que foi declarada a função alertContents() antes do fechamento da tag cole o seguinte código:

```
$("#ativo").click(function(){
   makeRequest('ativo');
});
 $("#inativo").click(function(){
   makeRequest('inativo');
});
```

Comment: Olá, tenho que importar a biblioteca ajax né ? 
estou recebendo o seguinte erro:
" ReferenceError: acao is not defined   at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"
meu botão:
<button value="" onclick="acao()"> <?php echo $ativo;?> </button>

Comment: Resolveu ? Se sim marque como a resposta correta no ícone em forma de 'v' ao lado esquerdo da pergunta

Comment: Testo assim que chegar em casa amigo mais a noite, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Eu que agradeço